# Excel automation: Range.Find

Tags: c#, excel

I want to implement [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=82) method in my c# program. But I am having trouble filling in the appropriate parameters in a line like

```
long FirstRow = myWorksheet.Cells.Find(
  What:="*", 
  After:=Range("IV65536"), 
  LookIn:=xlValues,
  LookAt:= xlPart, 
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows,
  SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
```

[Here is the documentation for the Range.Find method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
Range Find(
    [In] object What, 
    [In, Optional] object After, 
    [In, Optional] object LookIn, 
    [In, Optional] object LookAt, 
    [In, Optional] object SearchOrder, 
    [In, Optional] XlSearchDirection SearchDirection, 
    [In, Optional] object MatchCase, 
    [In, Optional] object MatchByte, 
    [In, Optional] object SearchFormat
);
```

So basically I don't know how to make the appropriate parameter objects.

**Update**
            Excel.Range range;

```
        object What = "*";
        object After = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "IV65536");
        object LookIn = "xlValues";
        object LookAt = "xlPart";
        object SearchOrder = "xlByRows";
        Excel.XlSearchDirection SearchDirection = Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext;
        object MatchCase = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object MatchByte = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object SearchFormat = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        range = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            What,
            After,
            LookIn,
            LookAt,
            SearchOrder,
            SearchDirection,
            MatchCase,
            MatchByte,
            SearchFormat
            );
```

Gives a "COMException was unhandled: Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

**Update #2**
Here is the method so far. The only thing missing is to set and return the range.

```
    public void RealUsedRange()
    {
        int FirstRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Row;

        int FirstColumn = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Column;

        int LastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Row;

        int LastColumn = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Column;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Framework 4.0? Which kind of error do you have using your syntax?

Comment: I am using the Framework 3.5. And I am aware of [dynamic type system](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42590) in 4.0 if that is what you are referring to. Currently I don't get any errors because I don't know the complete line yet to execute. For those parameters not in use, there should of course be a System.Reflection.Missing.Value object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested but this gives you the general idea:

```
long firstRow = myWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
    "*", /* What */
    Range("IV65536"), /* After */
    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, /* LookIn */
    Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, /* LookAt */
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, /* SearchOrder */
    Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, /* SearchDirection */
    Type.Missing, /* MatchCase */
    Type.Missing, /* MatchByte */
    Type.Missing /* SearchFormat */
    ).Row;
```

Since you can't use the optional argument syntax of VB.NET without C# v4, you need to supply all the arguments in order.  Supplying `null` might work for missing args but I'm pretty sure `Type.Missing` is the right filler.  Other than that it's just calling it like you would expect.

Here are some complete C# examples:

- [How to: Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I might be a step closer, but I'm still having the problem of not knowing how to set the parameters correctly. Any help is appreciated. I have updated my first post with the new code.

Comment: I've ported those parameters over and added a link with all the gory details.

Comment: Thank you. That was the hint I needed:-)

Answer (score 1):

Your next problem are the *LookIn*, *LookAt* and *SearchOrder* parameters. They shouldn't be a string, rather they are similar to the *SearchDirection* parameter:

```
object What = "*";
object After = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "IV65536");
object LookIn = Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues;
object LookAt = Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart;
object SearchOrder = Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows;
Excel.XlSearchDirection SearchDirection = Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext;
object MatchCase = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object MatchByte = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object SearchFormat = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

range = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
    What,
    After,
    LookIn,
    LookAt,
    SearchOrder,
    SearchDirection,
    MatchCase,
    MatchByte,
    SearchFormat
);
```